# remove space under first value ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to make a bar plot. The range of values is 1-7 and I would like to plot from .5 to 7. By default, it is plotting 0 to 7. When I change limits, the bars disappear. Thoughts?

This works, but has a big gap between the intercept and value of 1 (first possible value):

```
  ggplot(data=d2, aes(x=reorder(d2$variable, d2$value),y=d2$value,  
    fill=d2$component)) + geom_bar(width=.5, stat="identity",
    position=position_dodge(), size=.1) +         
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 7),breaks =  c(0:7),expand = c(0,0))+ 
    xlab("Readiness Subcomponent") + ylab("Readiness Score") +
    theme_minimal()+ 
    guides(fill=FALSE)+coord_flip()+scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "dark 
    orange"))
```

When I change scale_y_continuous to include (limits = c(1, 7),breaks =  c(1:7),expand = c(0,0)), all the bars disappear.

Comment: It is very bad practice to start a bar chart anywhere other than zero. It violates the principle of area being proportional to value.

Comment: http://serialmentor.com/dataviz/proportional-ink.html

Comment: huh. Thanks... I didn't know this.